# Performing a PATCH on a web API using WebClient (.Net 4.0)

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, webclient, http-patch

I've got a .Net 4.0 WinForms app which uses WebClient (as unfortunately I have not been able to get it to work with HttpWebRequest nor HttpClient, due to it being in .Net 4.0 and not .Net 4.5).

It consumes a Web API. It performs a GET on the API:

```
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)(3072);
    client.Headers.Add("someHeader", 123);
    string res = client.DownloadString("http://someurl.com/api/someendpoint");
    List<SomeObject> someObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SomeObject>>(res);
}
```

It also performs a DELETE:

```
using System.Net;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)(3072);
    client.Headers.Add("someHeader", 123);
    client.UploadValues("http://someurl.com/api/someendpoint", "DELETE", new NameValueCollection());
}
```

I now need to perform a PATCH, but I am pretty clueless as to how to do it. I've searched the internet, and most examples use HttpClient or HttpWebRequest. I haven't found anything that uses WebClient. So I need to send JSON something like this:

```
{
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "filename",
    "value": "somefile.pdf"
}
```

As a PATCH verb request to the API.
I have tried this:

```
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string json = @"[{
                    ""op"": ""replace"",
                    ""path"": ""//filename"",
                    ""value"": ""somefile.pdf""
                }]";

var serializeModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)(3072);
    client.Headers.Add("someHeader", 123);
    var response = client.UploadString("http://someurl.com/api/someendpoint/123", "PATCH", serializeModel);
}
```

But I get this exception:

**The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.**

(And this Patch API endpoint works well as it is currently in use by an Angular web app)

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the `Content-type` on the headers, just like so.

```
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

This will provide the media type for the endpoint to know what media type it is receiving. If you still get the error, you endpoint might not accept json.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. I added your suggestion, and now I get a (400) Bad Request error. The JSON patch document was malformed and could not be parsed. Instead of using a raw json string, i've created a "PatchDocument" object (with three fields: op, path and value), and then use JsonConvert.SerializeObject() to serialize, but I still get the 400 error. Not sure what is wrong with my JSON... the endpoint definitely accepts JSON.

Comment: Also your json string is using to many double quotation marks. It should be like this:

`string json = @"[{
                    "op": "replace",
                    "path": "//filename",
                    "value": "somefile.pdf"
                }]";`